# Play Youtube video in website with quality change setting and hide share button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, bootstrap-4

How do I play Youtube videos in a website with quality change setting and to hide the share button?

I have tried this player but there is not an option to change the video quality.

https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Answer (score 2):

You can't as of date.

Youtube revision history `showinfo` parameter is deprecated as of September 25, 2018. "Watch Later" and "Share" buttons were also part of this feature and they **can't be removed**.

Further you can never access/manipulate the DOM-contents of iframe served from different source due to security purposes. The web browser makes sure it's not possible.

The only hack that I'm aware of is that you can use css to hide it.

It's a common hack to use the `position: absolute;` `pointer-events: none;` styles to place it exactly over share icon of youtube player in your web application.

---

Here's a working fiddle for example, that I found:

> http://jsfiddle.net/7o5wzva2/2/

---

The code is something like:

```
.overlay-banner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 560px; // width of video player
    height: 58px; // height of banner
    background: transparent;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

This overlay will prevent clicks on share/watch later icons, which however can lead to be bad user experience.

**TLDR:** You can't as of date.